# k8s probes for spring boot services, best practices

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, istio

I'm configuring startup/liveness/readiness probes for kubernetes deployments serving spring boot services. As of the spring boot documentation it's best practice to use the corresponding liveness & readiness actuator endpoints as describes here:
https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot

What do you use for your startup probe?
What are your recommendations for failureThreshold, delay, period and timeout values?
Did you encounter issues when deploying isito sidecars to an existing setup?

Comment: 1. Rediness 2. This is very application dependant, use trial & error based on your startup times 3. None at all

Answer (score 5):

The startup probe is optional.

Originally, there were two types of probes in Kubernetes: readiness and liveness. However, people have encountered issues with slow-start containers. When a container takes a long time to start, Kubernetes does the first check on the liveness probe after initialDelaySeconds. If the check fails, Kubernetes attempts failureThreshold times with an interval of periodSeconds. If the liveness probe still fails, Kubernetes assumes that the container is not alive and restarts it. Unfortunately, the container will likely fail again, resulting in an endless cycle of restarting.

You may want to increase failureThreshold and periodSeconds to avoid the endless restarting, but it can cause longer detection and recovery times in case of a thread deadlock.

You may want to make the initialDelaySeconds longer to allow sufficient time for the container to start. However, it can be challenging to determine the appropriate delay since your application can run on various hardware. For instance, increasing initialDelaySeconds to 60 seconds to avoid this problem in one environment may cause unnecessary slow startup when deploying the service to a more advanced hardware that only requires 20 seconds to start. In such a scenario, Kubernetes waits for 60 seconds for the first liveness check, causing the pod to be idle for 40 seconds, and it still takes 60 seconds to serve.

To address this issue, Kubernetes introduced the startup probe in 1.16, which defers all other probes until a pod completes its startup process. For slow-starting pods, the startup probe can poll at short intervals with a high failure threshold until it is satisfied, at which point the other probes can begin.

If a container’s components take a long time to be ready except for the API component, the container can simply report 200 in the liveness probe, and the startup probe is not needed. Because the API component will be ready and report 200 very soon, Kubernetes will not restart the container endlessly, it will patiently wait until all the readiness probes indicate that the containers are all “ready” then take traffic to the pod.

The startup probe can be implemented in the same way as the liveness probe. Once the startup probe confirms that the container is initialized, the liveness probe will immediately report that the container is alive, leaving no room for Kubernetes to mistakenly restart the container.

Regarding the initialDelaySeconds, periodSeconds, failureThreshold, and timeout, it is really a balance between sensitivity and false positives. e.g., if you have a high failureThreshold and a high periodSeconds for the readiness probe, k8s cannot timely detect issues in the container and your pod continues to take traffic, hence many requests will fail. If you put a low failureThreshold and a low periodSeconds for the readiness probe, a temporary problem could take the pod out of traffic, that's a false positive. I kind of prefer default failureThreshold to 3 and periodSeconds to 5, successThreshold to 1 or 2.

BTW, don't use the default health check from Spring Boot, you always need to customize them. More details here: https://danielw.cn/health-check-probes-in-k8s

Answer (score 4):

I use the paths `/actuator/health/readiness` and `/actuator/health/liveness` :

```
readinessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 3
  httpGet:
    scheme: HTTP
    path: /actuator/health/readiness
    port: 8080

livenessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 3
  httpGet:
    scheme: HTTP
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
    port: 8080
```

for the recommendations, it depends on your needs and policies actually ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/ )

no istio sidecars issues with this :)

do not forget to activate the endpoints in properties (cf https://www.baeldung.com/spring-liveness-readiness-probes):

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your values, that's actually very helpful. Your init delay is quite high though, any specific reason for that?
Haven't you set up any startup probe? I was thinking of adding a tcpSocket probe but then that was ready immediately so I thought what's the point.

Comment: Oh yes its quite high in fact lol, its because the deployed microservice need more time than others to connect all the Kafka/MQ stuff to be up and running. To know how many time you need, just remove the probes, start your pod, check how long it takes to be up, running and ready to get traffic/connect with what is needed and use this time (However you can add a shortest period to wait, if your pod exits with no reason there is a chance that this is due to this). I didnt added tcpSocket probes for this project since this project is not intented to receive traffic but to connect to other stuff.

Comment: You don't need `management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true` for applications running in kuberentes. They're enabled by default.

Comment: yes you are right ! :p

Comment: Good Answer. In my case I played with `initialDelaySeconds` and `periodSeconds` to receive a bit more stable probing. A high level of `initialDelaySeconds` colides with CICD pipelies. Therefore, increasing `periodSeconds` helped me here. I used 30 Seconds for both.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Bguess answer and the part:

> for the recommendations, it depends on your needs and policies

Some of our microservices communicate with heavy/slow containers which need time to boot up, therefore we have to protect them with startup probes. The recommended way from [https://kubernetes.io/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) is to use liveness probe, what with the connection with spring-boot actuator endpoints results in:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/readiness
    port: 8080
  periodSeconds: 5
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
    port: 8080
  periodSeconds: 5
startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
    port: 8080
  failureThreshold: 25
  periodSeconds: 10
```

The above setup makes sure that we probe `liveness` and `readiness` when the application is fully started (has 10*25=250 seconds to do so). As the doc says:

> If such a probe is configured, it disables liveness and readiness checks until it succeeds, making sure those probes don't interfere with the application startup

Please note that
`management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true`
is not needed for the applications running in Kubernetes ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes))

> These health groups are automatically enabled only if the application runs in a Kubernetes environment. You can enable them in any environment by using the `management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled` configuration property.

Hence you need it if you want to check the probes for example locally.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but any good reason not to use `/health` as `startupProbe` (but keep using `/health/liveness` as `livenessProbe`?

Comment: @VincentC.It depends on your app. if you really don't have different states for liveness and readiness, then you won't need it.

But there is a reason for having two (now three) probes: failing the liveness probe will kill the pod, failing the readiness won't direct load to it. So you can use the readiness probe to prevent a pod from getting overloaded (of course you need to have the right architecture with multiple pods to do that). So you gain a more fine-grained controll - if you need it.